# Time-aware WMS Service

Tags: gis, wms

Am trying to develop WMS Service using ThinkGeo Map Suite WMS Server Edition. There is a requirement for viewing past data. I am new to GIS and as per my research seems it is possible to make WMS time-aware. Am specifically looking for a example or some suggestion which can point me in right direction how to achieve time-aware WMS using think geo SDK.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Some more info regarding the question.  Any inputs on how the datetime is passed from client to the server (as a parameter query string?) any format info, any WMS standards,  would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As per the WMS specification "Time" parameter has to be passed for enabling temporal rendering for maps.  The parameter format has to be in ISG 8601:2000 specification.

Format : 
ccyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ

EXAMPLE 1 : ccyy Year only 
EXAMPLE 2 : ccyy-mm Year and month
EXAMPLE 3 : ccyy-mm-dd Year, month and day
EXAMPLE 4 : ccyy-mm-ddThhZ Year, month, day and hour in UTC

Period format :
EXAMPLE 1 : P1Y — 1 year
EXAMPLE 2 : P1M10D — 1 month plus 10 days
EXAMPLE 3 : PT2H — 2 hours
EXAMPLE 4 : PT1.5S — 1.5 seconds

ThinkGeo WMS server edition do not have a property for this in GetMapRequest class, but can be handled using custom parameters.  If some one has a better solution would be helpful.